# How to tell if a user tabbed into a frame or clicked on a component on the frame

Tags: delphi

I have a problem with a TFrame descendant where when the user tabs into the frame the frame itself receives the focus instead of the first control on the frame.

Is there anyway of knowing if a user tabs into the frame vs the user actually clicking on a component within the frame?

I have implemented the OnEnter event and can set the focus to the first control but this may move the focus from a control (on the frame) that the user clicked on.

Comment: The frame should not be getting focus as a tab stop. Did you set the form's tab order properly? Is the `TFrame.TabStop` still `False` (the default)? I just did a quick test, with a `TEdit` on a new form, a new test `TFrame` with a single `TEdit` on it, set the form's `ActiveControl` to its own edit control, set the tab order to be the form's TEdit and then the frame, and ran it. I can tab between the two edits (one on the form, one on the frame) repeatedly with no stop in between on the frame.

Comment: Have you tried setting the TabStop property of the frame to False, while retaining TabStop = True for the controls within the frame? I think that way when the user tabs into the frame, focus will be received by the child control with the lowest TabOrder value... or perhaps I'm missing something in my understanding of your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the frame's `TabStop` property to False while retaining TabStop = True for the controls within the frame. That would change the nature of your problem, perhaps eliminating it entirely. In otherwords, the frame will no longer receive focus and you will not have to write extra code to set focus to the first child control. Now if you want to execute some code upon a control within the frame receiving focus or being clicked, you may implement the OnEnter or OnClick event of that control (not the frame's OnEnter event).

Comment: Brilliant - and so obvious!  My base TFrame descendant indeed had TabStop=True for some reason.  After turning that off and finding all references in dfms and fixing them up the problem is fixed.  Thanks to all.

Comment: @user2913735 I upvoted your question despite its simplicity. Would you consider returning the favour please. (:-D)

Comment: @Sam: user291375 may not have enough rep yet to upvote. And not all people believe in both upvoting and accepting.

Comment: @MarjanVenema the high unemployment rates in Europe and the US at the moment wouldn't be half the tragedy if common people had a better attitude towards one another.